# Implementing Cascading Deletes using SQLAlchemy Core

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables with a many (user_data_relation) to one (data) relationship.

I have been using SQLAlchemy Core and created Table objects for both.

```py
meta = MetaData()

Data = Table(
    "data", meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True),
    Column('data_id', String(100)),
    Column('text', String(25000)),
    Column('created_at', DateTime(timezone=True)),
)

User_Data_Relation = Table(
    "user_data_relation", meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('data_id', Integer, ForeignKey('data.id')),
)

meta.create_all(engine)
```

I am unable to delete a row from `data` now, since there is a ForeignKey constraint in the `user_data_relation` table.

I am trying to implement Cascading deletes, but the documentation only shows how to do it for ORM: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html#delete

Any ideas how to do this using `Table` objects and SQLAlchemy Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much the same as for ORM, you can specify [`ondelete`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html#on-update-and-on-delete) argument on [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey). If you want cascade deleting use:

```
ForeignKey('data.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

For your example, this query will be generated:

```
CREATE TABLE user_data_relation (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        data_id INTEGER, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id), 
        FOREIGN KEY(data_id) REFERENCES data (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I still get the following error:

IntegrityError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.IntegrityError) (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`user_data_db`.`user_data_relation`, CONSTRAINT `user_data_relation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`data_id`) REFERENCES `data` (`id`))')
[SQL: DELETE FROM data WHERE data.id = %s]
[parameters: (1,)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)

Is it possible that the issue is happening because I ran meta.create_all(engine) before without using `ondelete='CASCADE'`?

Comment: @Chris yes, it's possible

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, I haven't yet.

Comment: Are you trying to delete some records?

Comment: Actually, it seems like this guide works: https://5balloons.info/alter-table-to-remove-foreign-key-or-add-delete-cascade-mysql/